# "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

Tags: c#

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int numVal = -1;
        int numval = -1;
        bool repeat = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the perpendicular line finder!");

        while (repeat == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please write the gradient of the line");


            string userValue = Console.ReadLine();

            try
            {
                numVal = Convert.ToInt32(userValue);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid number");
                continue;
            }
            catch (OverflowException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That number is too large, sorry i cannot help you");
                continue;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("So the gradient is {0}? Y/N", numVal);
            string go = Console.ReadLine();
            if (go == "Y" || go == "y")
            {
                repeat = true;
            }
            else
            {
                repeat = false;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Please write the number that was added or subtracted");
            Console.WriteLine("but if it was subtracted leave the minus sign in");

            string userValue2 = Console.ReadLine();

            try
            {
                numval = Convert.ToInt32(userValue2);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid number");
                continue;
            }
            catch (OverflowException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That number is too large, sorry i cannot help you");
                continue;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("So the added or subtracted number is {0}? Y/N", numval);
            string go1 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (go1 == "Y" || go1 == "y")
            {
                repeat = true;
            }
            else
            {
                repeat = false;
            }

            int answer = -1 / numVal; 

            Console.WriteLine("A perpendicular line to y = {0}x+{1} is y = {3}x", numVal, userValue2, answer);   
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

It comes up with this error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
This happens when I run the code and get down to the second to last line of code.
I am new to c# and have no idea of what to do please help me.

Comment: Sorry, but the charter of this site does not extend to livestock.

Comment: **Read the error message**, which tells you exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine("A perpendicular line to y = {0}x+{1} is y = {3}x",
    numVal, userValue2, answer);
```

The format string refers to a non-existent argument `{3}`, replace with `{2}`.

Comment: Thanks but the answer it gives is always "y = 0x" can you explain why.

Comment: @Piggy `int answer = -1 / numVal;` does not look right. Should be something like `double answer = -1.0 / numVal;` (pay attention to `1.0`). Integer division cuts fractional part.

Comment: Thank you, I realized that the -1 was wrong but I didn't now how to change it.

Comment: @Piggy Alternatively, you could do `-1 / (double)numVal`. It would not be an issue in `numVal` would be `double`.